# vspace Before TikZ Picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, vertical-alignment

I am trying to make `TikZ` diagrams such that there is always 1cm of vertical space before the drawing. Is this possible?

This code does not compile.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\renewcommand{\begin{tikzpicture}}
{\vspace{1cm} \begin{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

text before
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(-3,3)--(2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
text after

\end{document}
```

Comment: may be you mean `\renewenvironment` there and sure not `\renewcommand` ...

Comment: I just tried changing it to `\renewenvironment` but it still does not work.

Comment: You shouldn't do this. Redefining tikzpicture in this way can only give grief. Define a new environment that you use either instead or around tikzpicture.

Comment: Yes... but this is the way to change an environment. You can not do it with renewcommand. Just trying to find a way (Many environments refuse to renew)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @UlrikeFischer advices, is easier to define your tikzpicture:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newenvironment{mytikzpicture}{\begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}}
{\
\end{tikzpicture}\end{center}\vspace*{1cm}

}

\begin{document}

text before

\begin{mytikzpicture}
   \draw(-3,3)--(2,1);
\end{mytikzpicture}
text after
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

For them who really want the space before (and not after) tikzpicture the code is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newenvironment{mytikzpicture}{\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}}
{\
\end{tikzpicture}\end{center}
}

\begin{document}

text before
\begin{mytikzpicture}
   \draw(-3,3)rectangle(2,1);
\end{mytikzpicture}
text after
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I had completely forgot about `\renewcommand` as I hadn't used it in forever.

Comment: Welcome. `\renewenvironment` is also a good command but many environments are refusing to renew... and in these cases @UlrikeFischer's advice is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could also change the `current bounding box` just before the `tikzpicture` is closed with `execute at end picture` option. This  option can be applied or not on `tikzpicture` parameters.

Following example enlarges tikzpictures to north with 1cm space. `show background rectangle` provides visibility to the change.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\tikzset{%
    add1cm/.style={%
        execute at end picture={\path (current bounding box.north)--++(0,1cm);
        }
    },
    background rectangle/.style={fill=blue!30}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[add1cm, show background rectangle]
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I change this example to add space at the bottom (e.g. south instead of north? I tried to replace `box.north` with `box.south` but that does not yield any effect.

Comment: @lanoxx did you also change (0,1) by (0,-1)?

Comment: Ah, it did not occur to me that I had to use a negative value, using a negative value works. Thanks a lot.